# Angular UI Router $stateParams doesn't update value, stays null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

here's my angular snippet

```
.state('patient',{
      url:'/patient/{id}',
      templateUrl: 'partial-patient.html',
      controller: "PatientCtrl",
      resolve: {
          post:['$stateParams', 'patientFactory', function ($stateParams, patientFactory) {
              console.log($stateParams);
              return patientFactory.getHRSessions($stateParams.id);
          }]
      }
  })
```

my url is `<a href="#/patient/{{patient.id}}/">{{$index+1}}</a>`

the $stateParams.id keeps returning null. I get the url properly formed as:

`https://<my-host>/#/patient/57f2106c2a2bc35043858143`

getting the output in console: `Object { id: null }`

Comment: obviously I'm doing a stupid mistake, I did this once before while following (https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial) and it was all fine!!

Comment: Try with `url:'/patient/:id'`

Comment: @mparnisari tried with that

Comment: What happens if you log `$stateParams.id` inside the controller?

Comment: @mparnisari I just tried that. Same thing. I get it as empty over there as well. I also changed the stateConfig to not worry about post and resolve, and keeping it really simple like    `.state('patient',{
      url:'/patient/{id}',
      templateUrl: 'partial-patient.html',
      controller: "PatientCtrl"`
that still gives me null

Comment: Ok. Can you try with `<a ui-sref="patient({id: patient.id})/">{{$index+1}}</a>`?

Comment: it has an error saying invalid state ref

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126429/discussion-between-pranay-shirolkar-and-mparnisari).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of problem. Basically, key is to check if there are *any* routing components that are overlapping your `<a>` tag or whatever you are trying to route with.

The parent (or rather grandfather) element of that `<a>` tag was a table. and there was a stupid

```
<table ui-sref="patient">
```

which was causing this problem. Changed it to

```
<table>...
```

and that did the  trick.